# How to build project from Intellij Idea command line

Tags: batch-file, intellij-idea

I am automating the build process of a project that uses outputs from Visual Studio 2017 and Intellij Idea. I am using a batch file to compile visual studio project and copy the generated .exe and .dll files to build folder where the install maker program is executed from batch file. I need to compile and build Intellij Idea project and copy the generated .jar files to build folder in the batch file. I haven't found command line options to do the same. Is it possible to do the same?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with IntelliJ. If you're looking for a jar, I assume it's a Java/JVM project. I'd suggest using a build tool for Java, which can be run from CLI, and is independent of IntelliJ.

Gradle, Maven, Ant etc are all good choices.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-intellij-idea-features-from-command-line.html

Comment: @Mikezx6r Yes, I used 'Generate Ant Build' menu option from Build  menu to generate build files and compiled and built it from Ant command line. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad I could help.